# write sql query to group variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new with writing Microsoft sql queries and I don't know how to handle my problem, I hope someone can help me with this :)

My data:
I have a dataset which contains 10 variables, of which one is the ID, one stands for year and the other 8 are tests which have yes or no as values.
I can group the 8 variables in 3 'groups'.

What I would like to do is write a statement that gives me the IDs/lines where there is a yes on all three clusters.

To clarify, one group consists of 4 variables, and the other groups consist of 2 variables each.

I want to write something that says if group 1 is yes and group 2 is yes and group 3 is yes then return ID. But I don't know how I can group the variables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right and you need to select id-s, which contains and least one 'yes' value in each cluster, then you need something like this:

```
select id from yourtable
where (c1_1 = 'yes' or c1_2 = 'yes' or c1_3 = 'yes' or c1_4 = 'yes')
and (c2_1 = 'yes' or c2_2 = 'yes')
and (c3_1 = 'yes' or c3_2 = 'yes')
```

In order to keep code clear you should normalize your database structure, i.e.:

```
create table yourtable (
    ID int primary key,
    [Year] int
)

create table answers (
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    youtable_id int references yourtable(ID),
    cluster_name varchar(10),
    question varchar(100),
    answer varchar(100)
)
```

Then query it like this to get ids with at least one positive answer in each cluster:

```
select yt.ID
from yourtable yt inner join answers a on (yt.ID = a.youtable_id)
inner join (select youtable_id as ID, count( distinct cluster_name) as positive_clusters from answers where answer = 'yes' group by youtable_id) as inn on (inn.ID = yt.ID)
group by yt.ID, positive_clusters
having positive_clusters = count(distinct a.cluster_name)
```

[Sample data](http://pastebin.com/RGEm35T3)

Comment: Thanks!! I used this, but now I would like to make more combinations as in c1 and c2 or c1 and c3 etc, but I would like to keep the code clear. Is there a pretty way to do this, or only as u suggested?

Comment: I've updated an answer. Another lazy man approach, especially if you don't plan to query for individual answers is to store your answers as string with separators, i.e. "yes;no;yes" and then just search for "yes" substring in where clause to find matching rows.